# Microsoft graph Api not getting the original shared event

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I am using microsoft graph api to sync my calendar with outlook. All of the events which are created by me are synced perfectly but problem happens when the organizer is someone other than me. If I update that event, it updates on my calendar but it remains the same on the organizer's calendar. I don't want to update that event I just want to resync back to the original organizer's event when my start/end datetime are messed up but graph api does not return the organizer's event date time. It returns the datetime which I have updated to.

Comment: You can't possibly change the organizer's copy without actually going to the organizer's mailbox - what if the organizer is not even on Office 365? What if you don't have the right to access the organizer's mailbox?

Comment: Thats the problem I am able to update the event in my mailbox. It does not update in the organizer's mailbox. I should not have been able to update in my mailbox either but outlook somehow allows this

Comment: Anyways I want my event's start time to go back to the original organizer's start time

Comment: Of course you can update an object in your own mailbox. Your Graph code is running under your identity. But how can you possibly expect to be able to access an arbitrary user's mailbox (organizer who might not even be hosted by Exchange)?

Comment: Of course I am not expecting it to update the other users mailbox. I am asking why are we even able to update an event whose organizer is not me

Comment: Does outlook refer to a copy of the original event or does it refer to the original event in the list event endpoint?

Comment: Any item in your mailbox is modifiable. For all Exchange cares, it is just some item in your own private Calendar folder. You can do whatever you want with it. It is always a copy - it cannot possibly reference anything outside. The updates between the organizer and attendee are handled by sending meeting requests/updates/cancellations. An attendee can reply with accept/decline/propose new time.

Comment: What if the organizer updates/cancels the event will I receive that update in my response in graph api?

Comment: Yes, if the organizer chooses to do so. If not, you won't receive a notification in your Inbox.